# Mostrar query en table

Tags: php, array, sql, optimización

Tengo mi consulta sql funcional. Si la imprimo con `print_r` me arroja toda la información que necesito, que son solo 5 registros con 3 datos:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [fecha_del_deposito] => 2018-05-08 [importe] => 60 [tipo_de_pago] => Mensualidad ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [fecha_del_deposito] => 2018-05-08 [importe] => 300 [tipo_de_pago] => Mensualidad ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [fecha_del_deposito] => 2018-05-08 [importe] => 360 [tipo_de_pago] => Mensualidad ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [fecha_del_deposito] => 2018-05-08 [importe] => 929 [tipo_de_pago] => Credito ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [fecha_del_deposito] => 2018-05-08 [importe] => 465 [tipo_de_pago] => Credito ) )
```

Y quiero mostrarlo en una tabla, pero no se como hacerlo de forma dinámica ya que lo que eh podido hacer es ponerlo de forma "manual" ocupando mucho espacio y nada practico, aqui un ejemplo de solo lo que eh echo para un solo registro:

```
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-2">Fecha del pago</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">Monto</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">Concepto</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <td>
        <?php
          if (!empty($pagos_unicos_del_ID[0]->fecha_del_deposito)) {
            print_r($pagos_unicos_del_ID[0]->fecha_del_deposito);
          } else {
            print "Sin registros";
          }
        ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php
          if (!empty($pagos_unicos_del_ID[0]->importe)) {
            print_r($pagos_unicos_del_ID[0]->importe);
          } else {
            print "Sin registros";
          }
        ?>
      </td> 
      <td>
        <?php
          if (!empty($pagos_unicos_del_ID[0]->tipo_de_pago)) {
            print_r($pagos_unicos_del_ID[0]->tipo_de_pago);
          } else {
            print "Sin registros";
          }
        ?>
      </td> 
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien que me pueda apoyar a una solución optima para esto?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacerlo con on foreach loop asi:

```
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-2">Fecha del pago</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">Monto</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">Concepto</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
        foreach($pagos_unicos_del_ID as $pago) {
            print "<tr><td>" . $pago->fecha_del_deposito . "</td><td>" . $pago->importe 
                . "</td><td>" . $pago->tipo_de_pago . "</td></tr>";
        }                      
      ?>          
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Tenia la noción pero no sabia como hacerlo, sin duda alguna aun me falta aprender mas, gracias por tu contribución :D